# Putty getting access denied everytime

Tags: putty

I am using `PuTTY` to connect to the server but every time I get access denied and after 3 attempts I can't even open putty. I get error as `Network error: Software caused connection abort`

I even checked the following things.

1. private key
2. automatic username and password

I entered the password of the key. Is it right password I am trying?
Or is there other passwords I should enter?

Comment: Is it the right password: How could we know? Are you trying to access as root? If so, access by password is usually disabled (with good reason). Can you check the server logs and configuration? Without more information, it could be almost *anything*.

Comment: Do you know, which kind of machine you a trying to access? This helps in isolating the problem since different OS behave differently with different presets. Also, if we know this is a VPS machine, it is different from a fresh installed machine in yoir local network.

Comment: You may have tripped a security mechanism that bans your ip on the server after so many bad attempts.

Answer (score 2):

Typing your error into google reveals:

> This error means that the network connection PuTTY tried to make to your server received no response at all from the server. Usually this happens because the server machine is completely isolated from the network, or because it is turned off.

In other words, the machine is not reachable.  If you have cygwin on your PC, you can try `telnet host port` from the dos prompt to see if you can access the port you are trying to connect to.  e.g. `telnet machinename 22`.  You should see some sort of a response - try comparing it to a server you know you can connect to vs. a made-up one you can't connect to.